Hiding parent div with javascript
How do I hide a div with a nested label class using javascript? For example I have the code below and I want to hide all the div.nbd-xlabel-wrap with the nested class label.nbo-disabled-wrap.
I tried this script


function hideLabels() {
  const labels = document.querySelectorAll('.nbo-disabled-wrap');

  labels.forEach(label => {
    let currentElement = label;
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      if (currentElement.parentElement) {
        currentElement = currentElement.parentElement;
      } else {
        break; // Reached the top of the DOM tree
      }
    }

    const targetDiv = currentElement.querySelector('.nbd-xlabel-wrap');
    if (targetDiv) {
      targetDiv.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
}

hideLabels();
<div class="nbd-xlabel-wrap">
  <div class="nbd-xlabel-value">
    <div class="nbd-xlabel-value-inner" title="Titanium">
      <input ng-change="check_valid();updateMapOptions('f1539147544370')" value="1" ng-model="nbd_fields['f1539147544370'].value" name="nbd-field[f1539147544370]" type="radio" id="nbd-field-f1539147544370-1" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty">
      <label class="nbd-xlabel ng-isolate-scope nbo-disabled-wrap" for="nbd-field-f1539147544370-1" nbo-disabled="!status_fields['f1539147544370'][1].enable" nbo-disabled-type="class"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <label for="nbd-field-f1539147544370-1"><b>Titanium</b></label>
</div>




are you trying to perform .nbd-xlabel-wrap:has(.nbo-disabled-wrap) { display:none; } using javascript?

Please [edit] the snippet to make a [mcve]

Depending on the event that will trigger the fonction if you have, you can add an attribute nbd-xlabel-wrap that you will get to display all elements with that class to display none

You did not explained what's the actual issue you're facing. Also, why the for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++)?

@JaromandaX, yes! that CSS worked. Thanks.

Instead of attempting multiple levels of parent traversal you can directly select and traverse the elements.
Modified code-
function hideLabels() {
  const wraps = document.querySelectorAll('.nbd-xlabel-wrap');

  wraps.forEach(wrap => {
    const disabledLabel = wrap.querySelector('.nbo-disabled-wrap');
    if (disabledLabel) {
      wrap.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
}

hideLabels();


I tried that script but it didn't work. Instead I found a solution using CSS.

@DJSingle you didn't find a solution using CSS, someone gave you the solution. Please accept his answer.

A css only solution (as per my comment to your question) is
.nbd-xlabel-wrap:has(.nbo-disabled-wrap) { 
    display:none; 
}

for example


.nbd-xlabel-wrap:has(.nbo-disabled-wrap) { 
    display:none; 
}
<div class="nbd-xlabel-wrap">
  <div class="nbd-xlabel-value">
    <div class="nbd-xlabel-value-inner" title="Titanium">
      <input ng-change="check_valid();updateMapOptions('f1539147544370')" value="1" ng-model="nbd_fields['f1539147544370'].value" name="nbd-field[f1539147544370]" type="radio" id="nbd-field-f1539147544370-1" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty">
      <label class="nbd-xlabel ng-isolate-scope nbo-disabled-wrap" for="nbd-field-f1539147544370-1" nbo-disabled="!status_fields['f1539147544370'][1].enable" nbo-disabled-type="class"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <label for="nbd-field-f1539147544370-1"><b>Titanium</b></label>
</div>



